Why aren't we bumping into objects outside of the visible range?
Apologies if this is too simple of a question for this site. My physics education stopped at the undergrad level. My 12 year old nephew asked me a question and I couldn't give him an answer. He asked, upon learning the human eye could only see within a limited range of frequency, “Why aren't we regularly bumping into objects outside of the visible range?”

Because basically everything around you interacts with visible light so you can see it. Thank you evolution!

You never seen a cat smash its face into a sliding glass door?

A related interesting thing is that objects that we can see can have features that are invisible to us, but are revealed by cameras/sensors that can record frequencies outside of the visible range (like ultraviolet (UV) or infrared (IR), and beyond). Some examples are layering in some sedimentary rocks that otherwise look uniform (no visible layers), coloration of some flowers that look plain to us but appear vibrant/multicolored to insects, heat "glowing" from the human body in infrared, different surface layers of the Sun revealed by observing it in various frequencies, etc.

@hft even humans do sometimes.

What exactly are you asking? Are you asking how humans avoid transparent objects, say glass? Are you asking why there aren’t many bump'able objects outside the visible range? Are you asking why most objects aren’t transparent even though we only see a limited spectrum?

Just to be clear, it this question predicated on the existence of physical objects with sufficient density for the to interact with humans (EG, a solid, not a gas), which exist outside of the visible human spectrum? For example, that there are invisible rocks, tress or life forms of some variety?

The wavelength describes what a photon looks like, but not what an object looks like; viewing an object is more complicated than a single number.

@fraxinus I once left a faceprint on a clear glass floor to ceiling window, right next to a doorway. Walked directly into it, full speed ahead. Fortunately I wasn't injured! I was very startled.

We do bump into things that do not reflect or emit visible light. Why do you think people carry torches in the dark?

First approach to this question: Turn the lights off (safety tip clear floor ways of Lego and similar impediments).

I would ask it slightly different... would it be possible for an 'object' to be completely transparent to our visible spectrum, and reflective to UV or IR or even higher/lower?

https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2018/03/i-walked-into-a-glass-door-911-recordings-from-apples-new-campus/

We do.
Birds fly into windows.
The first time I saw glasses with an anti reflection coating, I tried to poke my fingers through. I was curious why the frames had no glass in them.
You don't exactly bump into air, but you don't see it.
Cosmic rays and neutrinos fly through you all the time.
Infrared and UV photons bump into you without being seen.

Thank you. Aren't there solid objects within that range?

@MSIS the example with the birds is also often repeated by people, especially those in a maze made of glass walls and mirrors.

I know lots of people of have bumped into and even broken sliding glass doors because they couldn't see them. But glass does absorb light outside of the visible range, so you could see if you could see those wavelengths.

Humans can often notice even very clear glass because of reflection and refraction but the most important is that we have daily experience with glass and we know where to expect it. Many birds are not so fortunate. They have only occasional and very hard (often fatal) encounters with glass.

@MSIS glass is exactly that. It’s transparent because it has a “color” outside the range of visible light, and doesn’t (really) absorb in our range of perception. We only see it because of it’s nonzero refractive index which causes distortions and reflections, but that effect is present in any solid material anyway. (An answer touching on this would be nice, unfortunately I don’t have time for writing it.)

@user34722 Glaziers tend to put something on windows in transit, even if it's just an X of tape,  to let people more easily see the glass and prevent exactly this kind of accident. Of course once it's installed, they're kind of relying on people seeing "oh, it's a doorway, maybe there's a door there".

@Graham even after installation interior glass panels tend to have something on them to make them more visible.  Here it's a row of frosted dots ~50mm across and ~50mm apart, at eye height and door handle height.  It still needs to be obvious as people can do things like turn quite suddenly from a standing start too close to form a mental image of "doorway" or simply be distracted.

We don't bump into air, but we don't exactly know how to avoid a fart either

@sehe We technically bump into air all the time, it just moves out of our way. That's why you can feel air when you move around.

Apple built a fancy building at its HQ with glass walls that had this exact problem.

@pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong: To add to that, it is possible to trick humans into thinking that there is really clear glass in front of them when there isn't.. I was actually trying to find a version of this with a study where people removed the glass in a door with a push/pull bar for a mall, and noticed that most people would try to push the door open by leaning on the glass, even when it was not there. So it's not just a prank, or staged, where something like that happens.

@pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Back when I worked in an office, there used to be this one particular bird that would smack into the same couple of windows all the time. He had a distinctive pattern on one leg, so we knew it was the same one - we called him Captain Brain Damage. Fortunately, it was a third story window over the two-story warehouse side of the building, so he didn't have a big fall while he was disoriented, just a couple of feet.

In Australia, it's actually part of the building code to mark large pieces of glass in public areas.   Apparently in Israel too.  Probably elsewhere, but that's just what popped up on a quick search.

It's a good question. but the answer is basically evolution. Organisms that frequently bumped into things that they couldn't see/detect were easy prey and so quickly removed from the gene pool.

This is my favorite answer, but I feel like it only goes half-way. Yes, it's evolution. But why does evolution favor EM radiation in one range of frequencies over another? The original question specifically asks about the frequencies "outside the visible range." The answer from @Barmar comes closest: Most of the things on earth that we can bump into just happen to reflect or absorb EM radiation in the spectrum we call visible light. (Those objects may also interact with other frequencies, but for humans, the visible spectrum presumably gave evolution the greatest bang-for-the-buck.)

The answer and the comment by @SyntaxJunkie are good points. Additionally, having an appropriate radiation source is also relevant. On this planet, the sun is the most reliable source of radiation. Sources for e.g. x-rays are quite rare. There is not much benefit of developing senses for that. The sun emits quite a lot of infrared light, but the greater wavelength will probably give you less resolution. Ultra-violet is sensed by some birds and insects. We humans miss out on the beautiful coloration of some flowers because they have not been relevant to our ancestor's survival.

@SyntaxJunkie  "But why does evolution favor EM radiation in one range of frequencies over another?"  As François Jacob observed "Nature is a tinkerer, not an inventor". Evolution didn't favour one range over another; once it had something that worked it might tweak it, but it doesn't wonder whether a different range would be "better".
If you could wind evolution back to the Precambrian, then let it run forwards again, you might find eyesight being invented, but my guess is that the chemistry would be different, and so would the frequency range.

@SimonCrase: I don't understand the critique. I agree with you. I'm not sure what parts of my comment you disagree with. Our eyes didn't evolve to detect a frequency range because that's the visible range. We merely call it the "visual range" because that's the range our eyes have evolved to detect. That's why the I used the expression "...EM radiation in the spectrum we call visible light." I agree that "once it had something that worked it might tweak it....". Right. Once Nature found something that worked, it stuck with it. Isn't that what it means to "favor one range over another"?

@SyntaxJunkie I agree with you, and certainly didn't intend my comment as a criticism. I read "favour one range over another" as suggesting that there was some evolutionary reason for favouring 380–750 nm. Actually there is one argument for favouring this range - atmospheric opacity, but the precise range is a frozen accident.

@SyntaxJunkie the reason is because the Sun's peak emission frequencies (calculated via Wien's displacement law) are in the visible range, or phrased alternatively, we evolved eyes that detect light coming from our local star.

This sounds like a plausible hypothesis, but do we have any evidence that it's true?

Biologist here... I don't think evolution is actually a very good explanation here for any more than trivial reasons, the physics/chemistry of light are such that vision wouldn't really be possible any other way.

@BryanKrause "the physics/chemistry of light are such that vision wouldn't really be possible any other way" - I don't think I agree with this. We know that arthropod vision has evolved in an entirely different way to vision in vertebrates. If our world was bathed in infrared or ultraviolet instead of "visible" light then we would have evolved to see those wavelengths instead. Or maybe developed sonar like bats and dolphins.

@gandalf61 Longer wavelengths aren't strong enough to break modestly stable chemical bonds so they can't really be "seen", longer than that they pass right through animal-sized objects; shorter wavelengths cause direct chemical damage to too many things. Vertebrate and arthropod vision are very similar in all but the structure of the eye itself, which has little to do with wavelength sensitivity. Sonar would not be "vision", it's a different sense; I agree that sort of sense would likely be more common in an environment where light in the useful visual range was not present.

Reiterating the comment by Allure: the reason -- that 'visible light' is in the specific frequency range it is -- is because the Sun's peak emission frequencies (calculated via Wien's displacement law) are in the visible range, or phrased alternatively, we evolved eyes that detect light coming from our local star.

That's your belief. God is the Creator.

Something that hasn't been mentioned yet (perhaps because it's too obvious): if an object isn't transparent, but rather doesn't reflect any light of the visible spectrum, the first instinct might be to think that it will be invisible, but actually it will just appear black to us. See: Vantablack.
(Also, as @gerrit noted, if the object is hot enough it will glow inside the visible range anyway, and all the reflection/refraction/whatever won't matter for us to see it)

If you make Vantablack hot enough, it will be visible and non-black :) (Why didn't evolution develop thermal imaging?  It's a major advantage for nocturnal animals.)

@gerrit True. Although I think that then it wouldn't classify as "outside of the visible range".

@gerrit "Why didn't evolution develop thermal imaging?" — It did, humans just don't have it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_sensing_in_snakes

@yshavit Cool!  I tried to search the web for it, but the results for "animals seeing infrared" were all near infrared, not thermal imaging.

@gerrit Snakes got night vision, we got command of fire. I consider it a good trade!

I think your nephew is thinking something like this: Blue objects reflect blue light, and red objects reflect red light. But what about objects whose color is infrared? Why don't we bump into them?
And the answer is, we call those objects "black". Most objects are opaque to a large range of wavelengths above and below the visible spectrum. Maybe they have a color that we can't see, because they reflect strongly only at some wavelength we don't see. But, that means we just see them as black.
Many answers have pointed out that there are things we can't see, or have trouble seeing, but that requires the additional special property of transmitting the wavelengths we do see. Relatively few solid objects do that, as you know from experience.

As mmesser314 answered, in fact we do. When light finds the surface of a material, three different phenomena happens: transmission,absorption and reflection. Reflection is the simplest one, it is highly manifested in a mirror, for example. Transmission is what happens in a glass, and this is the reason why we see through it. Absorption is more subtle phenomena, but it is manifested when the objects are heated by light, for example. It is important to know that all the three will happen, what changes from one object to other is the amount of transmitted, reflected and absorbed light.
For an object to be invisible, in fact it should be transparent, i.e., it should transmit the majority part of incident light. The insight that is not trivial is that this in fact is a phenomenon that depends on the frequency of the incident light. Some objects could be transparent for some frequencies, but not for others.
It is not a coincidence that we can see in the range of frequency that we do. For this range, the water is transparent, for example, and it is important not only for the human eye. If some life form could see higher frequencies, more objects would be transparent (this is the reason why we use x-rays in tomography, for example).
Now, maybe you can impress your nephew telling him that the rainbow is bigger than what we can see (at least, it impressed me when I was a child).
EDIT; As pointed out in the comments, to transmit all (or the greatest part) of incident light is not enough to achieve invisibility, since we could see transparent objects due to refraction. Only a transparent object with refraction index close to the refraction index of its surroundings would be invisible to us.

I disagree that this is a fantastic question.

I hope we could be friends despite that

But, OK. Friends who strongly disagree :)

I'm going to remove the compliment, I need to listen to my friends more...

Refraction is also a major factor in why we can see even objects which transmit virtually all their incident light.

It might be good to add that you could probably still notice even a transparent object because of distortion unless its refractive index happens to be the same as that of the surrounding air.

Easy.
Glass doors are a simple example, but they are SOMEWHAT visible because of the refraction of the light. And the glass is not absolutely transparent either.
Just turn off the lights at night.
You don't see anything and you bump into object perfectly visible e.g. in 10 micrometer wavelength. You can try yourself with a thermal camera.
The ordinary matter we interact with (made of atoms and molecules) in its condensed state (liquids and solids) is "visible" in generally any wavelength from e.g. 1000m (subject to the natural resolution limits related to wavelength) down to the shortest gamma-rays we know of.
Human vision works in a rather narrow, but important range - where the spectral characteristics of an object profoundly relate to its chemical nature. This is why we see colors.
Human vision is also very, very precise in regards to angles, shapes and contours - this is how we see transparent objects (because of the refraction) and this is how we sometimes can see a heated air jet as well.
In short, there are few objects that are both solid in order to bump in them and invisible.

This is how one can honestly bump into both solid and invisible objects:
Some plastics and some other materials are transparent and have refraction characteristics very similar to water. If you immerse them in water, they become really invisible. You can then dive there and bump into them as hard as you want without seeing what you are bumping into.
This is also how some water organisms (e.g. jellyfish) are invisible or nearly-invisible in water. They are honestly invisible to other organisms that have worse vision than humans.

PMMA plastic in benzene is also a well known example (experiment not advisable. Benzene != Benzines != Benzin, and the stuff is toxic AF!).

Visible light encompasses a wide range of frequencies. So for something to be totally invisible to our eyes, it would have to be transparent in all these frequencies. Natural objects like this are extremely rare, possibly nonexistent. Air itself is transparent, but there are often substances suspended in it that are visible, such as clouds and smoke.
Glass is very transparent, but pure glass doesn't exist in nature, it's man-made. And even this isn't perfectly clear, we often see reflections and glints, and the edges of the glass are visible.
There are some other things in nature where we can't see details because they're outside our visible range. Many flowers have patterns that are only visible in the ultraviolet range that many insects can see; see A Different Light for examples.

Diamond may be the best example. It is transparent from DC to UV. And yes, they are rare.

@mmesser314 But you can see them because they sparkle.

@mmesser314 Natural diamonds are usually well visible because of their rough surface. See for example pictures here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond

And even polished diamonds are visible. When someone shows off a diamond ring, you can see the gemstone easily.

"Pure" glasses (eg optical glasses, quartz glass) still refract and reflect. And the key to making glass less reflective is not making it purer but coating it with very defined thicknesses (hint: the thickness has a relation to the wavelength, these coating are kinda resonant!) of metal salts (eg in camera lenses or high end spectacles)

I feel like some of the answers miss that this question actually works in reverse.
Why did our - and most animals' - eyes evolve to see EM radiation specifically in this range of frequencies? Because that was the most useful and practical one to focus on as a way to get information about the environment. It just so happens that it's the "just right" EM frequency range for most solid matter to interact with it in some way, and the one provided abundantly by the Sun for everything to reflect, so it was very useful. Infrared is the other one that could be even more useful, as everything emits it, and some animals do have limited infrared detection capabilities, but the downside there is that your own sensor organ would also emit infrared (since it's just a property of things at a certain temperature), so there would be a lot of noise. Good low frequency infrared cameras need to be cooled down with liquid nitrogen, that's not easy to do for a living organism.
Meanwhile, microwaves just aren't common in nature, and radio frequencies even if they were would be way too imprecise for the scales and distances living beings operate on. Lions aren't hunting plane-sized gazelles from 20 km away. On the other end of the scale, UVs aren't as abundant and the higher in frequency you go, the more dangerous things get. You could I suppose imagine some biological organism that metabolises and concentrates uranium or some other radioactive element to develop an organ that acts as a gamma emitter to use these radiation for sensory purposes. But that has several downsides. It's complicated, it's expensive, it's dangerous (high energy radiation equates cellular damage for virtually all life), and since gammas are so penetrating they are most useful in transmission, not reflection. Maybe such animals could work in packs, using each other's sources to identify what's in between them. That might be a cool idea for a speculative biology story set on an alien planet, but on Earth, light is just that much more convenient!
Consider also, now we can create glass and a few other solid things that are also transparent. Still not so perfectly non-interacting as to be invisible (the refraction gives them away), but enough to fool someone who isn't paying attention. But such things did not exist in the ancestral environment. As far as the bird that crashes into it is concerned, glass is an eldritch magical forcefield beyond its comprehension.

Your nephew has a really good intuition for why vision is so interesting! As several of the above answers have noted, sometimes we do bump into objects because their interactions with visible light did not render them visible to us. Typically, this is because they did not reflect (very common) or emit (less common, but happens with transparent fluorescent or phosphorescent “glowing” material) enough visible light for us to detect them. This can happen either in the case of the brightly lit sliding glass door others have pointed out, at least as long as the light doesn’t scatter in such a way that you notice it. But it can also happen in the case of objects that absorb too much light and are rendered black enough that we don’t notice them. Imagine walking down a gently lit hallway with the walls, floors, and ceilings painted with vantablack. You would not know whether to continue straight or turn because there would be no light reflecting off the walls to make it obvious if you were about to run into something. It would be a truly disorienting experience. Another special case is when there simply isn’t enough light around for us to see efficiently in the first place. I certainly remember playing games in the dark as a kid and ramming my shinbones against dark wooden tables in the dark despite being able to see some other dimly lit objects just fine. If we were to take a spacecraft into deep space far away from a source of light we would be in serious danger of collision from darkly colored objects unless we were very carefully checking for them all the time. We simply wouldn’t see them coming! The fact is that we don’t usually run into things because we have evolved to operate during daylight hours where the solid objects are sufficiently illuminated and reflective of visible light that we will not be in danger from our surroundings. Our entire definition of visible light is just the light we have evolved to see, and so it makes sense that solid objects on earth just happen to be visibly opaque to us. When we operate outside those boundaries we really do run into trouble!

The "visible range" refers to frequencies. Objects are not frequencies. So it doesn't make sense to refer to an object as being "outside the visible range". You may be using that as shorthand for "objects whose color is outside the visible range", but color isn't the same thing as frequency, either. Each frequency has a particular color associated with it, but that color can be achieved by lots of other combinations of frequencies. For instance, there is a frequency of light that is perceived as "yellow", but "red" and "green" light put together are also perceived as "yellow".
"Color" refers to how we, as humans, perceive combinations of frequencies, so it doesn't really make sense for there to be a color outside of the visible range. Now, you may ask "Okay, what if something has nothing but frequencies outside the visible range?" Well, first of all, that would be rather unusual. Most things reflect some light across the spectrum. Something perceived as "red" is reflecting mostly red light, but is also reflecting some green and blue light. So even if something mainly reflected UV light, it would probably reflect some light in the visible spectrum. Something that doesn't reflect any light in the visible spectrum is perceived as "black", but when we talk about "black", we generally mean something much darker than most things. Even things that are "black" still reflect some light. And even if something reflected no light at all, if it's surrounded by things that do reflect light, then you'd be able to tell that it's there because it would block light from those other things.
Another possibility is that something might be transparent. However, transparent objects generally have a refraction index that's different from air, and so if they are curved, they act like a lens. And even if the object is flat, the edges will still be visible. So the only way you'd bump into it is if it's so big that it looks like there's room between the edges. For instance, a glass door has edges that are several feet apart, so if you think that the space between them is empty, you might try to walk through that space. But if you have, say, a glass cube one foot across, that's going to be easy to see if you are paying attention and have decent lighting.

To your 12 year old nephew:

Fantastic question! The thing is most things do scatter visible light to our eyes, light we can see. The light they scatter could be coming from the sun, or a bulb or some other conventional light source. So we naturally don't collide with them.
Remove the surrounding sources of light, say complete darkness, and you would start bumping into things left and right. This doesn't mean those objects aren't emitting light in frequencies invisible to us. For e.g. a FLIR camera would see them. So would some other animals which have more advanced vision than ours. Hot objects, like a warm kettle, emit light too - we can't see the heat, but can definitely feel it. When you get a call, your smartphone is emitting (and receiving) a kind of light too. You can't see that either but it's carrying your voice and video to the other person. None of this means you can't see the kettle or your phone.


The answer is our eyes evolved to see most "things" that are solid. Including glass that even if its not 100% visible sometimes in certain situations it can be hard or impossible to see. In fact there are some situations where unkown people accidentally break a glass wall when they do not see it but, a lot of things make that not happen every day like for example reflection. that makes it not entirely transparent.
Besides glass is not natural at least not that transparent, The only "almost as transparent" component is frezed wayer (again only in certain situations) but is clearly visible even if partially transparent.
And so far no one has found somethig truly and 100% invisible and solid yet (at least for houmans that is not glass). If anyone find such please post it here for everyone to know.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

A black object does not reflect/transmit/emit any visible (to our eyes) light.
Even if something is completely black, but the background is not completely black, you will see the outline of the black object. Only if the background is completely black, like in a completely dark room, only then will you not see a black object.
It is also good to know that light is very good at bouncing around. Or: many things are good at reflecting, or at least a little. If you have a completely dark room and even a really tiny hole or some minor light source, the light will bounce around and light up almost everything a little bit. Unless you are in a very large room. So even something completely black is hard to hide without seeing anything else.
The only option not to see an object is if it is completely black against a completely black background (or any other same color), or if it would let any light coming from behind it pass right through it unchanged (like glass), bend the light around it (e.g. diagonal mirrors reflect light around it, maybe even big gravity wells (think black holes) bending the path of light itself), or perfectly reproduce it (e.g. a picture or tv screen with a camera behind it to reproduce what you would see in place of the picture or tv). And all of these examples are likely not perfect and still visible by some aberrations if you look closely.

Bit off topic, but to clarify the diagonal mirrors:
Example of light (the horizontal and vertical lines) bouncing with mirrors (the diagonal lines) around an object (x):
    /---\
    |   |
--- / x \ ---



To an observer on the right, the object x could be hidden as the observer would just see what is on the left (with some minor differences).
